# cryptsetup: dm-crypt plain mode using keyfile AND passphrase

Tags: encryption, dm-crypt, cryptsetup

I feel a keyfile and a passphrase provide different benefits. They can not be obtained in the same way (one you need to physically acquire, the other one you need to know). Thus, I think there is great benefit in encrypting my data using BOTH of these. That way, if one gets compromised the encryption is still intact.

Using dm-crypt in plain mode, I want to use BOTH. By default, dm-crypt uses a passphrase, and I can change that to a keyfile easily. But they seem to be the same kind of input (as in, the keyfile becomes your passphrase if provided). Using both --key-file and --verify-passphrase therefore doesn't work.

Any workarounds here to use both?

Comment: https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Custom_Initramfs#Encrypted_keyfile

Comment: @frostschutz Thanks but that refers to LUKS use, no? I'm using plain dm-crypt...

Comment: Of course it refers to LUKS. That's what everyone uses. But it's the same principle for plain mode. Or you could mix the ideas, a LUKS encrypted key can still open a plain encrypted disk. @yaegashi's answer is the same idea again, only it uses gpg instead of cryptsetup to encrypt the key.

Answer (score 5):

You can store the actual passphrase for `cryptsetup` (possibly a very long and complicated string) in a file encrypted by GnuPG (or any other tool) with another passphrese you can remember.

First encrypt a passphrase string with `gpg` to get encrypted `keyfile`:

```
# echo 'long-long-passphrase-for-cryptsetup' | gpg -q -c --cipher-algo AES256 -o keyfile 
Enter passphrase: <- Enter another passphrase you can remember
# file keyfile 
keyfile: GPG symmetrically encrypted data (AES256 cipher)
```

Then decrypt `keyfile` to feed that passphrase to the stdin of `cryptsetup --key-file -`.

```
# gpg -qd keyfile | cryptsetup plainOpen --key-file - /path/to/image volname
```

The similar suggestion can be seen in the [cryptsetup manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/cryptsetup.8.html).

The example above uses the symmetric encryption (`gpg -c`) for simplicity.  It would be much better and desirable if you could adopt the public key encryption!